# How to fix crash in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I'm creating an app for a sensor and when I start it the app crashes.

> I tried the app on 2 different phones and 2 emulators but crashes un every device.

Here is the MainActivity.java file:::

```
package com.example.ir_sensor;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    openMenu = findViewById(R.id.Open_menu);
    closeMenu = findViewById(R.id.Close_menu);
}

View openMenu = findViewById(R.id.Open_menu);
View closeMenu = findViewById(R.id.Close_menu);

public void menu() {
    if (openMenu.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        closeMenu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else if (closeMenu.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
        openMenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

}
```

Here is the activity_main.xml file:::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/LOGO"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="248dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo_int_lukka" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/Close_menu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/LOGO"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_less" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/Open_menu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/openmenu"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/LOGO"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_more" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/menuLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="380dp"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/houseMenu"
            android:layout_width="4dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/housemenu"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/house_menu" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2">

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/IR_LED"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/ir_led"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ir_led" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2">

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/alarmSign"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/alarmsign"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/on_off__alert" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2">

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/gridline380FromTop"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="380dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="380dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/gridline48FromLeft"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="48dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the Logcat:::

> 2019-08-12 17:14:39.966 9648-9648/com.example.ir_sensor E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.ir_sensor, PID: 9648
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ir_sensor/com.example.ir_sensor.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3194)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:249)
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:182)
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:520)
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:191)
>           at com.example.ir_sensor.MainActivity.(MainActivity.java:18)
>           at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
>           at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
>           at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:43)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1243)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3182)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
>   What can I do?

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference at` there's your error

Comment: If any answer helped you, please select one of them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error is that you are defining the `openMenu` and `closeMenu` variables, outside the `onCreate()` method. The thing is however that before onCreate you haven't defined your view, so getting the view by id before the view has been defined results in a `NullPointerException` (the program can't find the variable you were asking for and crashes). So do this:

```
package com.example.ir_sensor;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        openMenu = findViewById(R.id.Open_menu);
        closeMenu = findViewById(R.id.Close_menu);
    }

    View openMenu;
    View closeMenu;

    public void menu() {
        if (openMenu.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            closeMenu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else if (closeMenu.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
            openMenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes only in onCreate()

Comment: or if you are using fragments in onCreateView()

Comment: I did what you said but now when I start the App it says that the app keeps stopping. I've put it not only in onCreate because otherwise, it didn't work, it didn't build.

Comment: Post the new log together with the new code

Comment: I've uploaded the questions with the log and the log.

Comment: but you need to remove the findViewById from outside the onCreate(). Only use findViewById on onCreate(). Not outside.

Comment: Like this?
`@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         View openMenu = findViewById(R.id.Open_menu);
         View closeMenu = findViewById(R.id.Close_menu);
    }`

Comment: I'll copy it now.

Comment: Glad to help you :)